# How to launch an instantiated object in a certain direction from the center of the screen based on the mouse pointer position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am creating a simple game where you are locked in the center of the screen and must shoot things as they move toward you.  The problem I am currently facing is that I can not launch a bullet in the direction of my mouse cursor.  Currently, my code looks like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

    PlayerScript playerScript;
    public float xVel;
    public float yVel;
    public float direction;

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerScript = FindObjectOfType<PlayerScript>();
        //playerScript.AngleDeg is the direction the player is facing (based on mouse cursor)
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, playerScript.AngleDeg);

        direction = transform.rotation.z;

        //from the unit circle (x = cos(theta), y = sin(theta)
        xVel = Mathf.Cos(direction *  Mathf.PI);
        yVel = Mathf.Sin(direction *  Mathf.PI);

    }

    void Update () {
        transform.position += new Vector3(xVel,yVel,0);
    }
}
```

currently, when I run the code, the bullet shoots at an angle which is at the direction that is correct when the player is orientated sideways, but when orientated vertically is a full 45 degrees off.

Answer (score 0):

Attach this as a component to your instantiated bullet object and it should work.

```
    Transform playerTransform;
    float bulletSpeed;
    Vector3 directionToShoot

    void Start()
    {
    playerTransform = FindObjectOfType<PlayerScript>().gameObject.transform;
    bulletSpeed = 3f;
    //Direction for shooting
    directionToShoot = playerTransform.forward - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    void Update()
    {
    //shoot
    transform.Translate(directionToShoot * bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```